# What model i have to choose for the admin controller mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is only 1 admin view in my project. In this view administrator will work with many entities (each of that have personal DB context).
Should I create a Big model which contents all my entities? Sounds stupid. Or  should I somehow to connect many models to 1 view (never heard about this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass more than one model into a view, you'll have to pass everything in one model. This is kind of the same idea as connecting many models to one view, you're just collecting the models in one model first.

For example, if you're trying to pass, say `Person`, `Product` and `Item` into one view, you'll just need to make an `AdminViewModel` that has those things as properties, and set them in the controller before you pass in the model.

Comment: Seems, it`s the only way. But its so uncomely.

Comment: Maybe, but if you have one view that touches lots of entities, you could consider splitting it into a few smaller views.

Comment: You could do something like:

- In the main `AdminViewModel` pass the IDs of your entities.
- In the admin view, do, for example `Html.RenderPartial("ViewPerson", "Person", new { id = Model.PersonId })`
- So then in the person controller, you can take that ID, build up the smaller model and render the partial view using it.

This is really just a style choice, though, it's up to you what you want to do with it (and more importantly, how your entities and code are laid out).